# Vertical align multiple image with different height

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I got a Carroussel script which display all the users of the site i'm working on. This carroussel displays the avatar of the users.
I try to align verticaly the avatar's but i can't get it right...

I also check the other subject on the internet (like http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/oJeAK) , but nothing really match my needs...

Here is my CSS code :

```
#author-sorter {
    padding: 20px 30px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    width:900px;
}
#author-sorter > * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#author-sorter ul li {
    float: left;
}
#author-sorter ul li a {
    width: 48px;
    height:48px
}
#author-sorter ul li a:hover img, #author-sorter ul li.now a img {
    border: 1px solid #bcd001;
    width: 48px;
}
#author-sorter ul li.now {
    position:relative;
}
```

I made a live version here : http://jsfiddle.net/ev2wD/

Any tips ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ev2wD/2/)**

**The HTML:**

```
<div id="author-sorter">
    <div class="jcarousel-container jcarousel-container-horizontal" style="position: relative; display: block;">
        <div class="jcarousel-clip jcarousel-clip-horizontal" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
            <ul class="pagination jcarousel-list jcarousel-list-horizontal" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; margin: 0px; padding:  0px; width: 902px; display:table-row;">
                <li class="now jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-1 jcarousel-item-1-horizontal" style="width: 82px;" jcarouselindex="1"><a href="?author_id=43" id="43"><img width="46" height="48" class="wp-user-avatar wp-user-avatar-48 alignhttp://0.gravatar.com/avatar/ad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536?s=48 avatar avatar avatar-48 photo" alt="Alterre Bourgogne" src="http://rare.lfdb.fr/files/2013/08/Alterre_logo.gif"><span class="arrow"></span></a>

                </li>
                <li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-2 jcarousel-item-2-horizontal" style="float: left; list-style: none outside none; width: 82px;" jcarouselindex="2"><a href="?author_id=51" id="51"><img width="48" height="15" class="wp-user-avatar wp-user-avatar-48 alignhttp://1.gravatar.com/avatar/ad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536?s=48 avatar avatar avatar-48 photo" alt="ARPE PACA" src="http://rare.lfdb.fr/files/2013/08/Logo_ARPE-PACA_2010_BD-150x49.jpg"><span class="arrow"></span></a>

                </li>
                <li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-3 jcarousel-item-3-horizontal" style="float: left; list-style: none outside none; width: 82px;" jcarouselindex="3"><a href="?author_id=50" id="50"><img width="48" height="29" class="wp-user-avatar wp-user-avatar-48 alignhttp://0.gravatar.com/avatar/ad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536?s=48 avatar avatar avatar-48 photo" alt="AREC Poitou-Charentes" src="http://rare.lfdb.fr/files/2013/08/AREC_logo-150x91.gif"><span class="arrow"></span></a>

                </li>
                <li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-4 jcarousel-item-4-horizontal" style="float: left; list-style: none outside none; width: 82px;" jcarouselindex="4"><a href="?author_id=47" id="47"><img width="48" height="38" class="wp-user-avatar wp-user-avatar-48 alignhttp://0.gravatar.com/avatar/ad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536?s=48 avatar avatar avatar-48 photo" alt="AREHN" src="http://rare.lfdb.fr/files/2013/08/Arehn_logo.gif"><span class="arrow"></span></a>

                </li>
                <li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-5 jcarousel-item-5-horizontal" style="float: left; list-style: none outside none; width: 82px;" jcarouselindex="5"><a href="?author_id=48" id="48"><img width="48" height="32" class="wp-user-avatar wp-user-avatar-48 alignhttp://1.gravatar.com/avatar/ad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536?s=48 avatar avatar avatar-48 photo" alt="ARENE Ile-de-France" src="http://rare.lfdb.fr/files/2013/08/ARENE_logo2009-150x102.gif"><span class="arrow"></span></a>

                </li>
                <li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-6 jcarousel-item-6-horizontal" style="float: left; list-style: none outside none; width: 82px;" jcarouselindex="6"><a href="?author_id=52" id="52"><img width="48" height="48" class="wp-user-avatar wp-user-avatar-48 alignhttp://1.gravatar.com/avatar/ad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536?s=48 avatar avatar avatar-48 photo" alt="ARER" src="http://rare.lfdb.fr/files/2013/08/Logo-arer-150x150.jpg"><span class="arrow"></span></a>

                </li>
                <li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-7 jcarousel-item-7-horizontal" style="float: left; list-style: none outside none; width: 82px;" jcarouselindex="7"><a href="?author_id=44" id="44"><img width="48" height="48" class="wp-user-avatar wp-user-avatar-48 alignhttp://1.gravatar.com/avatar/ad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536?s=48 avatar avatar avatar-48 photo" alt="ARPE Midi-Pyrénées" src="http://rare.lfdb.fr/files/2013/08/ARPE_logosimple-150x150.jpg"><span class="arrow"></span></a>

                </li>
                <li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-8 jcarousel-item-8-horizontal" style="float: left; list-style: none outside none; width: 82px;" jcarouselindex="8"><a href="?author_id=49" id="49"><img width="48" height="31" class="wp-user-avatar wp-user-avatar-48 alignhttp://0.gravatar.com/avatar/ad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536?s=48 avatar avatar avatar-48 photo" alt="CERDD" src="http://rare.lfdb.fr/files/2013/08/CERDD_Logo2004.jpg"><span class="arrow"></span></a>

                </li>
                <li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-9 jcarousel-item-9-horizontal" style="float: left; list-style: none outside none; width: 82px;" jcarouselindex="9"><a href="?author_id=46" id="46"><img width="31" height="48" class="wp-user-avatar wp-user-avatar-48 alignhttp://0.gravatar.com/avatar/ad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536?s=48 avatar avatar avatar-48 photo" alt="OEC" src="http://rare.lfdb.fr/files/2013/08/OEC-98x150.jpeg"><span class="arrow"></span></a>

                </li>
                <li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-10 jcarousel-item-10-horizontal" style="float: left; list-style: none outside none; width: 82px;" jcarouselindex="10"><a href="?author_id=53" id="53"><img width="48" height="24" class="wp-user-avatar wp-user-avatar-48 alignhttp://0.gravatar.com/avatar/ad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536?s=48 avatar avatar avatar-48 photo" alt="RAEE" src="http://rare.lfdb.fr/files/2013/08/RAEE_logo.jpg"><span class="arrow"></span></a>

                </li>
                <li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-11 jcarousel-item-11-horizontal" style="float: left; list-style: none outside none; width: 82px;" jcarouselindex="11"><a href="?author_id=45" id="45"><img width="48" height="27" class="wp-user-avatar wp-user-avatar-48 alignhttp://1.gravatar.com/avatar/ad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536?s=48 avatar avatar avatar-48 photo" alt="RARE" src="http://rare.lfdb.fr/files/2013/08/LogoRARE-e1377163403654.png"><span class="arrow"></span></a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="jcarousel-prev jcarousel-prev-horizontal" style="display: block;"></div>
        <div class="jcarousel-next jcarousel-next-horizontal" style="display: block;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
#author-sorter {
    padding: 20px 30px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    width:900px;
}
#author-sorter > * {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#author-sorter ul li {
    float: left;
}
#author-sorter ul li a {
    width: 48px;
    height:48px;
    display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
#author-sorter ul li a:hover img, #author-sorter ul li.now a img {
    border: 1px solid #bcd001;
    width: 48px;
}
#author-sorter ul li.now {
    position:relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
display: table-cell;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice! I'm not really used to table-cell display :)

Comment: You are welcome :) I just upadated my answer with some changes. You can check. - @x_vi_r

Answer (score 0):

I simplified the example to be used by other people:

add the CSS style `display:table-row;` and `display:table-cell;` to `<ul>` and `<li>` respectively.

```html
<ul  style=" display:table-row; ">

    <li  style="display:table-cell;" ><img width="46" height="48" src="a.gif"/>
    </li>
    <li   style="display:table-cell;"><img width="146" height="48" src="b.gif"/>
    </li>
    <li  style="display:table-cell;"><img width="26" height="48" src="c.gif"/>
    </li>
    <li  style="display:table-cell;" ><img width="246" height="48" src="d.gif"/>
    </li>

</ul>
```