# How to vertically align both image and text side by side in a div

Tags: html, css

I have seen the answer the answer to ''[Vertical Align in a Div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div)
" and followed the Adam's answer. My problem is to how to have both image and text side by side and the text being at the middle of the image.

[My JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6AQ4z/)

My tried code

**CSS**

```
.outerContainer {
    display: table;
    width: 100%; /* width of parent */
    height:200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border:1px solid green;
}
.outerContainer .innerContainer {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="outerContainer">
          <div class="innerContainer">
            <div >
             <img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danleech/simple/512/facebook-icon.png' height=50px width=50px>
                <p style='display:inline-block;font-size:10px;'>Some Text</p>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

My problem is to get that 'Some Text' side and at the middle of the image

**NOTE:**I know I shouldn't use inline-block here. But I don't know how to get it.

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527974/vertical-align-multiple-image-with-different-height/18528104#18528104 - @Lonely

Comment: something like **[this](http://jsbin.com/obOkOYU/1/)**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The img is supposed to have the vertical align property.

```
<img src='http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danleech/simple/512/facebook-icon.png' height="50" width="50" style="vertical-align:middle;">
```

Comment: Not too sure. I've only ever really used the vertical-align property on img tags. Give me an example on jsfiddle of text not aligning in the center next to a header tag.

Comment: The reason that the text on the right hand side looks a bit off is because of the different font sizes. One is 20px and the other is 15px. Try setting the second paragraph tag to vertical-align:middle and it looks a little bit better. http://jsfiddle.net/6AQ4z/5/