# How do i align two pictures with different heights HTML

Tags: html, css

[I am working on a website as school project and i want to align these two pictures. One of them the Öppettider is way to low.]

[This is what the website looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acGT2.png)

Here is the code for the pictures

```
<p>&nbsp; </p>
<img src="../oppettider.gif" width="" height="500" alt=""/>
<img src="la-carte-förrätter.gif" width="680" height="2608" alt=""/>
```

Comment: Please, provide some CSS and html here

https://codepen.io/

Comment: how the pictures wont come with it then

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vertical align multiple image with different height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527974/vertical-align-multiple-image-with-different-height)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use flexbox:

```
<div class="images-flex">
     <img src="../oppettider.gif" width="" height="500" alt=""/>
     <img src="la-carte-förrätter.gif" width="680" height="2608" alt=""/>
</div>
```

then in css:

```
.images-flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

align means one after another ?
the best way is using bootstrap u can easily do it

according to me the best way of doing is using grid system use this link and try to implement ...

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/